# count instances of duplicates in a colum of a .csv file

Tags: python

```
import re, csv
import os,shutil
import io,json, collections
from collections import Counter, defaultdict,deque

sn=0 #1st column
p_f=1 #2nd column


reader = csv.reader(open("C:/Users/gurbir.sahota/Documents/python_csv_file_program/remove_duplicates.csv", "r"), delimiter='\t')


f= csv.writer(open("C:/Users/gurbir.sahota/Documents/python_csv_file_program/final.csv", "w"))


g=open("C:/Users/gurbir.sahota/Documents/python_csv_file_program/remove_duplicates.csv",'r') 
with open("C:/Users/gurbir.sahota/Documents/python_csv_file_program/remove_duplicates.csv", 'r') as infh:
    data = csv.reader(infh)
    next(data)  # skip header

    seen = defaultdict(set)

    counts = Counter(
    row[sn]    
    for row in data
    if row[sn] and row[p_f] not in seen[row[sn]] and not seen[row[sn]].add(row[sn])   
    )


print(counts.most_common())
#want to count instances of the number 2 in [('VFGRP15040030', 2), ('VFGRP15370118', 2), ('VFGRP15150113', 2)]


x=len(list(csv.reader(open('C:/Users/gurbir.sahota/Documents/python_csv_file_program/remove_duplicates.csv'))))
print('# of rows including header=');print(x)
count_pass = sum(1 for row in csv.reader(open('C:/Users/gurbir.sahota/Documents/python_csv_file_program/remove_duplicates.csv')) if row[1] =='pass')
print('# of passes=');print(count_pass)

count_fail = sum(1 for row in csv.reader(open('C:/Users/gurbir.sahota/Documents/python_csv_file_program/remove_duplicates.csv')) if row[1] =='fail')
print('# of fails=');print(count_fail)

#count_retest = ??




g.close
#f.close
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# to get duplicates and their frequency for a column 
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

with open('data.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    # here we take as example column number 1
    cn = Counter(map(itemgetter(1), r))
    # print item that appears more than once in the column
    for k, v in cn.items():
        if v > 1:
            print(k,v)
```

Comment: Your previous code worked if I removed op from op.itemgetter. Thanks